# Line up label with fa icon in my navbar with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I may be being a bit of a perfectionist but I want my text to line up with the centre of the icon...

[image: compass and town label]

I would like to move the compass down a few pixels but using padding and margin just changes the size of the menubar they reside in. Also position relative and bottom moves both.

My code is

```
<p class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="townlabel">
<i class="fa fa-compass fa-2x" id="compassicon"></i>Glastonbury
</p>
```

Css

```
#townlabel {
display: inline-block;
}
#compassicon {
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to increase the margin of the #compassicon element? maybe margin: 10px 5px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align: middle` to fix this.

```
#townlabel * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tudrLv03/

Comment: Great thanks, although I didn't add the * at first and it didn't work. I'm not sure what the * does

Comment: @PaulLeppard `*` matches any element.

Comment: Thanks @PaulLeppard, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#compassicon {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If that doesn't work, then this will, although it's the less "correct" way to do it:

```
#compassicon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

You may need to adjust the `top` value to get it exactly how you want it.